# Pretty dump variable/object in Symfony 2.*?

Tags: symfony, var-dump

When developing stuff I need to output the state of some instance in order to inspect it.

While using CakePHP I always had a debug() function which does some kind of var_dump inside a <pre> html element, so the content is readable.

Is something similar in Symfony 2.x too?

Comment: no, you could install something like xdebug to do that automatically for you while using the `var_dump` function.  The strength of Symfony2 is to use the best tools in the PHP community, instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: In the end, I could build something for what I need, but I wanted to know if it is there already.

Answer (score 16):

```
exit(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($someVar));
```

Answer (score 8):

use

\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($user);

Answer (score 5):

As of today, one of the best ways to debug in Symfony that I know of is the [Ladybug Bundle](https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle). Its output is similar to xdebug's, but it has some nice features, like a collapsible tree structure for arays or automatically linking to documentation pages (supporting standard PHP, Doctrine and Symfony).

You can find some great examples of its use on the README.

Comment: At the moment I am using Ladybug and it doesn't work well at all. I am not able to open all collapse... I tried on Chrome, FF and IE. Also I often get memory issue with this tool.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a new function in Symfony - dump(), have a look at http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-vardumper-component